# NestJS Logger: Can't set logger types in main.ts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, nestjs

When trying to set logger types in `main.ts` like it is shown [in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger):

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule, {
  logger: ['error', 'warn'],
});
await app.listen(3000);
```

VS code doesn't give me an option of `LogLevel[]`, only `boolean` and `LoggerService`, so logging doesn't work. I'm using:

```
"@nestjs/common": "^6.8.2",
"@nestjs/core": "^6.8.2",
"@nestjs/jwt": "^6.1.1",
"@nestjs/passport": "^6.1.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.8.2",
"@nestjs/swagger": "^3.1.0",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^6.2.0",
```

Comment: For me this works. Can you try to remove your `node_modules` and rerun `npm install` to make sure you have the right dependencies installed?

Comment: @KimKern Thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest dependencies are not installed although they are already declared in your `package.json`. In order to make sure you actually have the wanted versions installed, remove your `node_modules` folder and rerun `npm install`.